# What is the recommended wire size for a device that outputs 5V/3A?

Tags: wire-size

I am planning to design a diy 18650 power bank and I want to know what AWG would be appropriate for this application. The device is expected to output 5V/3A and the wire length connecting the components will be approximately less than 5cm. I would gladly accept your suggestions and recommendations. Thank you.

Comment: Just go 22AWG for that, for availability and workability.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple answer:**

Look it up in a chart like this and call it done

[Wire Gauge and Current Limits Including Skin Depth and Tensile Strength](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)

**More complex answer:**

Determine the voltage drop and wire temperature that you can tolerate. Then consider what balance of wire diameter to efficiency you want within those limits.

You can probably ignore wire temperature for just 3A, assuming you use wire that's not hair thin.

**Side note:**

Wire doesn't have a limit as to how much current it will carry, it just gets hotter and drops more voltage for the same current as you reduce the wire diameter. For low current applications (like milliamps) you will probably want a choose a larger wire than strictly necessary, just for the mechanical strength.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a table of AWG cable parameters, among which is maximum current-carrying capacity as a function of wire gauge.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge